# Youtube API v2 - Authentication differs between queries?

Tags: php, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-php-client

Using the Youtube API, I'm trying to write a script listing all of the uncaptioned videos a user owns, whether public, private, or unlisted. First, I authenticate using the user's credentials:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; // the Zend dir must be in your include_path
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

try {
    $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
    $username = $Youtube_Login["Username"],
    $password = $Youtube_Login["Password"],
    $service = 'youtube',
    $client = null,
    $source = 'NAME', // a short string identifying your application
    $loginToken = null,
    $loginCaptcha = null,
    $authenticationURL);
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $err[] = $e->getMessage();
    return false;
}
```

Then, I try to return a list in two ways. I first try to use a Query to pull just the uncaptioned videos from the database:

```
try{
    $query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
    $query->setParam('caption', 'false');
    $query->setParam('author', $Youtube_Login["Username"]);
    $query->orderBy = 'viewCount';
    $videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query);
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    $err[] = $e->getMessage();
    end_script(false);
}
```

However, the private and unlisted videos are missing from the results. So for the second attempt, I use the getUserUploads() function to pull ALL the videos, and then check them for missing captions:

```
try{
    $videoFeed = $yt->getuserUploads($Youtube_Login["Username"]);
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    $err[] = $e->getMessage();
    end_script(false);
}

foreach ($videoFeed as $videoEntry) {
    foreach ($videoEntry->link as $link) {
        if($link->rel == "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.captionTracks"){
            if($link->extensionAttributes['http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007:hasEntries']['value'] == 'false'){
                // Video has no caption entries, print entry info
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This returns me the correct result, but at the cost of efficiency, speed, and data transfer. Since there's only so much data transfer Google allows per day, and since the amount of videos is large (and increasing), this is a subpar solution.

Is there any way to correctly authenticate the first attempt, in order to find the unpublished and unlisted videos my client also needs listed? Or, another way entirely which does not involve downloading and traversing the entire list of videos?

Thank you!

**Update:**

I've discussed this with my employer, and OAuth is not an option, 2 or 3 legged.

So, is there simply absolutely no way at all to authenticate for the newVideoQuery() function? Is it purposefully hindered to be unable to retrieve a video's personal data, even for the video owner?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Oauth authentication process. It will be more secure and you will end up with a token you can use instead of repeating the auth process each time.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2

Comment: Is there a way to do that without forcing a manual login from the user, just using their credentials? This is a script that should run in command line, on a remote server, and I do not wish for a redirect.

Comment: Look into 3-legged OAuth for web apps.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe this solves the problem. I am currently authenticating correctly, as I do have access to the private listing in the second attempt. The problem is getting an authenticated user result from the first attempt.

Unless the OAuth process would use the the getVideoFeed() function in a different way?

Comment: It does, you would get a token, and you add that token to your query. It can be used repeated times until it expires.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say you need to use 2-legged Oauth not 3.

Comment: Alright, so I spent last night trying to figure it out with no real results on my end. Any links, or links to examples, for this?